# NodeJS: Send out emails (such as notifications to my application's users) No need for it to be authenticated or receive emails

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, koa, koa2

In NodeJS can we use an email that does not exist (like no-reply@example.com) to send emails?
Can we do that using the latest version of Nodemailer https://nodemailer.com/ ?   If

Comment: @AndrewL64  Of course you can, mail servers have no idea if `no-reply` is real or not.   But if the email gets spam blocked that's another story..

Comment: How can you do that in Nodejs?

Comment: Just set `direct: true` in the transport options.  But bear in mind depending were the email is going it has a higher chance of getting spam blocked, and auto retry etc is not automatic.  So, ideally you want to set your SMTP at `example.com`, Auth with this, and depending on server may allow `from` that's not equal to Auth details.  Without any form of Auth you would likely be relay blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for nodemailer shows that you get specify the sender address, so: yes.

From addresses are entirely freeform and under the control of the sender. Without combining them with tools like SPF, they are easy to forge.

You will, of course, need a real SMTP server to send the email through.

Comment: How can I do this in NodeJS / Koa ? setting up an SMTP server?

Comment: You don't (at least not in practice). You find a hosting service that provides you with one.

Comment: You don't need an SMTP server to send emails.  NodeMailer will look at MX records to work out were to send messages.   Saying that having your own SMTP Server does have it's advantages,

Comment: Basically, I just want to send out emails (such as notifications to my application's users) I do not need it to be authenticated or receive emails.

Answer (score 0):

Nodemailer is a great application. Let me demonstrate some example code with nodemailer

```js
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Comment: However, in my case it is a non-existent email address hence, I can not authenticate or configure it. Hence, in my experience this doesnt work. Please correct me if I am wrong and guide me to correctly implement this.

Comment: Edit : You cannot authenticate it if the email does not exist, Nodemailer will throw an error, so I think you should just try and send a mail to yourself in order to test it. :)